# Why are doubles added incorrectly in a specific Visual Studio 2008 project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

Trying to port java code to C++ I've stumbled over some weird behaviour. I can't get double addition to work (even though compiler option /fp:strict which means "correct" floating point math is set in Visual Studio 2008).

```
double a = 0.4;
/* a: 0.40000000000000002, correct */

double b = 0.0 + 0.4;
/* b: 0.40000000596046448, incorrect
(0 + 0.4 is the same). It's not even close to correct. */

double c = 0;  
float f = 0.4f;  
c += f;
/* c: 0.40000000596046448 too */
```

In a different test project I set up it works fine (/fp:strict behaves according to IEEE754).

Using Visual Studio 2008 (standard) with No optimization and FP: strict.

Any ideas? Is it really truncating to floats? This project really needs same behaviour on both java and C++ side. I got all values by reading from debug window in VC++.

**Solution:** _fpreset(); // Barry Kelly's idea solved it. A library was setting the FP precision to low.

Comment: Can you post a small complete test program along with the exact command line used to compile (see output window etc.), which demonstrates the problem? The only way I can reproduce is by using 0.0f + 0.4f instead.

Comment: Can we assume you are aware of the imprecision of floating point types? Being accurate to 7 decimal places is usually considered ok since the default printing precision is 6.

Comment: @Evan, his example is off by more than would be explained by floating point imprecision.

Comment: Well, his example is off by exactly what would be explained by single-precision floating point precision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is perhaps you are linking against a library or DLL which has modified the CPU precision via the control word.

Have you tried calling `_fpreset()` from `float.h` before the problematic computation?

Comment: It must be something along those lines, but is 0.0 + 0.4 even a computation? Can't it be evaluated at compile time? Checking the disassembly might establish whether the runtime float mode has anything to do with it, or whether something has gone wrong at compile time.

Comment: Sure it can be, but if it were that simple, it would be easy to reproduce, no?

Comment: I dunno, maybe something else in the project is specifying /fp:stupid or equivalent. My personal favourite would be a source file isn't newline-terminated and therefore the program has undefined behaviour, although I don't hold out much hope of ever seeing that cause a bug in the wild...

Comment: Spot on! It was a library setting the FP precision to 32bit (a directx DLL in my case). Thanks! :)

Comment: @barry-kelly do you know which functions can set the floating point precision? I suspect I have the same issue, but don’t want to put _fpreset all over the place, but rather right after the offending library...

Comment: _set_controlfp, _control87, _controlfp, __control87_2, maybe others.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's certainly truncating to floats. I get the same value printing `float f = 0.4` as you do in the "inaccurate" case. Try:

```
double b = 0.0 + (double) 0.4;
```

The question then is why it's truncating to floats. There's no excuse in the standard for treating `0.0 + 0.4` as a single-precision expression, since floating point literals are double-precision unless they have a suffix to say otherwise.

So something must be interfering with your settings, but I have no idea what.